# Sync Local Folder on SDCard on Android Device with Google Drive Programatically

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-drive-android-api

I am making an app which requires syncing of my local folder on SDCard with Google Drive. I am unable to find any concrete document which can tell me how I can sync the local folder on my SDCard on the device and whether at all it is possible or not?

I have seen the documents here https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders

and also the sample codes here https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

I can successfully create folders and files on Google drive using its native API but I just want to know if there is any simple way to just sync the local folder stored on my SDCard to google drive programatically

I am new to Android Development and I would appreciate if someone could guide me on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Drive Android SDK doesn't include any functionality to automatically sync local folders. You would have to build that logic yourself, using the API methods available.